# Editing viewmodel children in a Jquery dialogue

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to accomplish this and would like to know if its a correct way.

I have a viewmodel like this

```
Foo()
     FooChildren()
     SelectedFooChild()
```

I have a div where a knockout for-each (on FooChildren) outputs a template. Each item in this template is of a javascript child viewmodel  FooChildren(). In each template the user can click on a button on a row and this is to set the $parent.SelectedFooChild observable which is bound to fields in a Jquery dialog.

How do I best bind this selected data modified in the  jqueryUI dialogue back to the parent data to which it is derived?

I have something like this

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: FooThings">
  <button data-bind="onclick: open-JqueryUI-Dialogue-And-Set-The-selected-Item-To-This-Row/>
</div>
```

I wonder if I could skip the whole selected item thing and bind the dialogues data directly to the SelectedFooChild? I think if it was done this way it would be more trouble than its worth because I don't see a way of setting a binding on the dialogue that binds to the clicked row in the foreach row. I'm used to doing this sort of thing in Flex though.

I hope that is clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<button data-bind="click: parent.SelectedFooChild" />
```

You set the data item clicked to be the selected child, and bind that to your dialog. I do think that this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Can I not just do this: <button data-bind="click: parent.SelectedFooChild($data) />

Comment: Pretty sure that will execute the command on binding, not on click. You would be assigning the result of the command to the click event. If you want to do it in one go, use parent.SelectedFooChild. I'll update the answer.

Comment: No problem! Though if it has solved your problem, it'd be great if you marked it as the correct answer. :)